# Uniform integrability of a sequence of functions.

Tags: sequences-and-series, self-learning, uniform-convergence, uniform-integrability

I am considering the following sequence of functions. I think it converges pointwise to $0$ because the intervals in the domain in which the *nth* function is greater than zero eventually shrink and become the point $0$ in the domain.

$$f_n:x\to
\begin{cases}
n^2x,  & \text{if $0\le x \le\frac1n$} \\
-n^2x+2n, & \text{if $\frac1n \le x\le \frac2n$}\\
0, & \text{if $\frac 2n \le x \le 1$}
\end{cases}$$

What could I say about $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^1f_n(t)dt$$ and $$\int_0^1 \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(t) dt$$
I know that uniform convergent sequences of functions can be integrated term by term. Here I would verify uniform convergence of my sequence. But how?

Moreover, is my reasoning correct as for pointwise convergence of this sequence?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that the sequence $(f_n)$ converges pointwise to zero. However, it does not converge uniformly, because
$$\sup_x f_n(x) = n$$
which does not converge to zero as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Uniform convergence is a sufficient condition, but not necessary, to be able to interchange the limit and integral. In this case, we can check directly that the interchange is invalid:
$$\int_0^1 f_n(x) dx = 1$$
for all $n>1$, because the graph of $f_n$ is a triangle with height $n$ and base $2/n$.
Therefore, 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_0^1 f_n(x) dx = 1$$
On the other hand, $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n(x) = 0$ for all $x$, so
$$\int_0^1 \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n(x) dx = 0$$

Comment: I think the supremum of $f_n$ is $2n$ because it is the vertex of the triangle. Am I wrong? Furthermore, whenever I need to test uniform convergence of a sequence should I study the supremum of the *nth* function? What would you suggest Bungo?

Comment: @Charlie: Notice that the function is increasing on the interval $[0,1/n]$ and decreasing on $[1/n,2/n]$. Therefore the maximum occurs at $x = 1/n$, and the maximum value is $f(1/n) = n$. In general, a sequence $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to a given limit $f$ if and only if $\sup_x |f_n(x) - f(x)|$ converges to zero. In this case $f(x) = 0$, so the condition takes the simpler form $\sup_x |f_n(x)| \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: @Charlie: P.S. I recommend plotting the function $f_n$ if you're not sure why the maximum is $n$. The graph should be a triangle, starting at $(0,0)$, rising to $(1/n,n)$, and then falling to $(2/n,0)$.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much Bungo! Useful answer! I can visualise it now. And I totally agree with you as for the supremum of the *nth* function.